# CONEXION A BASE DE DATOS SYMFONY 5 (.env)

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, symfony

Me estreno con esta pregunta a ver si hay suerte y alguien puede echarme un cable.

Estoy creando un proyecto con symfony y necesito acceder a distintas bases de datos (cada cliente una bbdd) y no se como hacerlo porque en el archivo ".env" solo deja configurar una bbdd parece, pero me extraña mucho.

¿Alguien sabria como hacerlo? Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: en el archivo .env puedes añadir las variables que quieras. La cuestion es que tendras que modificar el archivo config/packages/doctrine.yaml y añadir ahi una nueva connection (aparte de la default), y usar las nuevas variables que añadas en el .env

Answer (score 2):

puedes añadir varias connections en symfony. Para ello tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

en el archivo .env, añade las variables que necesita una nueva connection. Por ej, añade otras nuevas, como:

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
DATABASE_USER=db_user
DATABASE_PASS=db_password
DATABASE_URL=127.0.0.1
DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DATABASE_NAME=db_2_name
DATABASE_2_USER=db_2_user
DATABASE_2_PASS=db_2_password
DATABASE_2_URL=127.0.0.1
DATABASE_2_HOST=127.0.0.1
DATABASE_2_PORT=3306
DATABASE_2_NAME=db_2_name
```

he añadido las "database_2_*". Ahora en el archivo config/packages/doctrine.yaml, busca la seccion donde se añaden las connections. Tienes una default, añade la database_2:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    connections:
      default:
         ------  < deja lo que tengas aqui
      database2:  <-esto es lo que añadimos
        driver: 'mysqli'
        charset: utf8mb4
        server_version: '5.6'
        user: '%env(DATABASE_2_USER)%'
        password: '%env(DATABASE_2_PASS)%'
        host: '%env(DATABASE_2_HOST)%'
        port: '%env(DATABASE_2_PORT)%'
        dbname: '%env(DATABASE_2_NAME)%'
        default_table_options:
          charset: utf8mb4
          collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

con esto, ya tienes una nueva conexion llamada `database2`. Usala cuando necesites conectar a la segunda bbdd.